# INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE is only inserting

Tags: mysql, on-duplicate-key

I am currently using MySQL and PHP 7's PDO and I am attempting to either insert or update a customer to a data table. The code that I am currently using is:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("
INSERT INTO `customer` (
  `customer_id`,
  `household_id`,
  `first_name`,
  `last_name`,
  `suffix_id`,
  `birthday`,
  `customer_since`,
  `referral_id`,
  `phone`,
  `email`,
  `address`,
  `city`,
  `state_id`,
  `zip_id`)
VALUES(
  :customer_id,
  :household_id,
  :first_name,
  :last_name,
  :suffix_id,
  :birthday,
  :customer_since,
  :referral_id,
  :phone,
  :email,
  :address,
  :city,
  :state,
  :zip_id
) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  `customer_id` = :customer_id2,
  `household_id` = :household_id2,
  `first_name` = :first_name2,
  `last_name` = :last_name2,
  `suffix_id` = :suffix_id2,
  `birthday` = :birthday2,
  `customer_since` = :customer_since2,
  `referral_id` = :referral_id2,
  `phone` = :phone2,
  `email` = :email2,
  `address` = :address2,
  `city` = :city2,
  `state_id` = :state2,
  `zip_id` = :zip_id2;");

// Parameterize the query 
$stmt->bindValue(':customer_id', (isset($_POST['customer_id']) || empty($_POST['customer_id'])) ? null : $_POST['customer_id']);
$stmt->bindValue(':household_id', $household_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':first_name', $_POST['first_name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':last_name', $_POST['last_name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':suffix_id', $suffix_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':birthday', $_POST['birthday'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':customer_since', (isset($_POST['customer_since']) || empty($_POST['customer_since'])) ? null : $_POST['customer_since'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':referral_id', $referral_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':phone', (isset($_POST['phone']) || empty($_POST['phone'])) ? null : $_POST['phone'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':email', (isset($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['email'])) ? null : $_POST['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':address', $_POST['street'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':city', $_POST['city'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':state', $_POST['state'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':zip_id', $zip_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$stmt->bindValue(':customer_id2', (isset($_POST['customer_id']) || empty($_POST['customer_id'])) ? null : $_POST['customer_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':household_id2', $household_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':first_name2', $_POST['first_name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':last_name2', $_POST['last_name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':suffix_id2', $suffix_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':birthday2', $_POST['birthday'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':customer_since2', (isset($_POST['customer_since']) || empty($_POST['customer_since'])) ? null : $_POST['customer_since'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':referral_id2', $referral_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':phone2', (isset($_POST['phone']) || empty($_POST['phone'])) ? null : $_POST['phone'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':email2', (isset($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['email'])) ? null : $_POST['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':address2', $_POST['street'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':city2', $_POST['city'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':state2', $_POST['state'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':zip_id2', $zip_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

The `customer_id` field is the unique, auto-generated field for the `customer` data table.

Whenever I create a new customer, it works fine. However, whenever I attempt to update an existing customer, it will create a new row in the `customer` table instead of updating the existing one with a new auto-incremented `policy_id` value. I even confirm that there is a customer_id value by calling: `echo $_POST['customer_id']` to make sure that there is a value whenever I expect it to update.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

There was a typo in my original post, I said `policy_id`, but I meant to say `customer_id`.
Also, the `customer_id` is the primary key and is the unique, primary, auto-incremented field.

**Update #2**

Even though somebody took it upon themselves to remove my PHP and PDO tag, here is the output of my $_POST:

```
[household_id]   => 1
[customer_id]    => 1
[first_name]     => Jane
[last_name]      => Doe
[suffix]         => 
[phone]          => (555) 555-1234
[email]          => user@email.com
[street]         => 1234 Main St
[city]           => Anytown
[state]          => 1
[zip]            => 12345
[birthday]       => 2017-10-27
[customer_since] => 2017-10-27
```

I am also using the Insert...On Duplicate Key successfully on the following values:

- Household_ID
- Suffix
- Referral
- Zip

These either insert a new value in their respective tables which then generates the appropriate foreign key or updates the existing value to remain the same.

Comment: Before Insertion you need to check weather the data you posted is already in database if yes, Run the UPDATE query else run INSERT query.

Comment: @GyandeepSharma That's the whole purpose of `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Comment: Is `customer_id` the primary key? Also where is this `policy_id` you talk about?

Comment: How does `policy_id` relate to `customer_id`?

Comment: I agree with what @imlokesh said - you say "unique, auto-generated field" but mysql will be specifically looking at the `PRIMARY KEY` defined on the table, which is often, but needn't necessarily be, the auto-generated field.

Comment: @GregHNZ well, it must at least be a *component* of the pk, and for innodb it must be the pk itself

Comment: @GregHNZ I've updated my post to reply to your comments.

Comment: I found my error, and it was with the PHP (so no thanks to the guy who removed the PHP tag...). I had forgotten the not operator (!) prior to isset whenever I was binding the parameter values.